# The module load only works for the first node, not all. Is there's a way to specify the full path to the math command when launching remote kernels

Tags: parallelization, remote-access

Running a *Mathematica* .m file in cluster for parallel computing. But get an error "bash: math: command not found". Is there's a way to specify the full path to the `math` command when launching remote kernels. Here is the code what I am doing...

```
module load Mathematica/9.0.1

Needs["SubKernels`RemoteKernels`"]

LaunchKernels[RemoteMachine/@StringSplit[Environment["LSB_HOSTS"]]]; 

n=10000;
S1=ParallelSum[L[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}];
```

I am getting these errors:

```
SubKernels`Protected`kernelFlush::time: 
   Operation LinkWrite timed out after 15. seconds.

KernelObject::rdead: Subkernel connected through remote[c150] appears dead.

SubKernels`Protected`kernelFlush::time: 
   Operation LinkWrite timed out after 15. seconds.

KernelObject::rdead: Subkernel connected through remote[c150] appears dead.

SubKernels`Protected`kernelFlush::time: 
   Operation LinkWrite timed out after 15. seconds.

General::stop: Further output of SubKernels`Protected`kernelFlush::time
     will be suppressed during this calculation.

KernelObject::rdead: Subkernel connected through remote[c150] appears dead.

General::stop: Further output of KernelObject::rdead
     will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Comment: My code was working for the Mathematica 8. But now on clusters they have Mathematica 9. so it start giving me some errors. For that Ioad "module load Mathematica/9.0.1". But still there is errors. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I wrote [this little package](https://bitbucket.org/szhorvat/crc/src/1cca33d8615e07805073a95778d9e6e33950ddd8?at=default) for our cluster, which is definitely different enough from your cluster that it won't work there.  But you might get some inspiration from it.  I forgot the details, sorry, but I remember spending 1.5 days to figure out how to work around our cluster's undocumented idiosyncrasies (e.g. that `ssh` wont' work).